# docker failed to register layer windows 10 version 1709 (build 16299.1087)

Tags: windows, docker

I'm on Windows 10 version 1709 (build 16299.1087). Ultimately, I want to work with Windows containers. When I do `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1709` I get

```
1709: Pulling from windows/nanoserver
407ada6e90de: Extracting  81.04MB/81.04MB
9ef95ce817ec: Download complete
failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 3221225794: output:
```

Not sure how to grok the exit status or the empty error message. Any thoughts?

EDIT:

Running `docker info` gives me:

```
 Kernel Version: 10.0 16299 (16299.637.amd64fre.rs3_release_svc.180808-1748)
 Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.1087)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 7.958GiB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rebooting my machine fixed the problem....

Answer (score 0):

Check your Docker for Windows service and ensure that it's set to run Windows containers.  In your setup, you have to switch the service back and forth:

[image]

You can see some explanation here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/933

Comment: Yeah, I've confirmed that docker desktop in the system tray says "switch to Linux containers" which I guess means that it's set for windows containers. I've also tried restarting the docker server and toggling the container type control to Linux then back to windows. Also, if I was set to Linux containers, the error message is something like, "no matching manifest" and the download would've never started